# cgo calling share library: cannot find lib or function?

Tags: go, cgo

I'm using the sample code of chapter 13 of *The Go Programming Language* as below:

```
$ cat bzip2.c
#include <bzlib.h>

int bz2compress(bz_stream *s, int action,
                char *in, unsigned *inlen, char *out, unsigned *outlen) {
    s->next_in = in;
    s->avail_in = *inlen;
    s->next_out = out;
    s->avail_out = *outlen;
    int r = BZ2_bzCompress(s, action);
    *inlen -= s->avail_in;
    *outlen -= s->avail_out;
    s->next_in = s->next_out = NULL;
    return r;
}

$ cat usebzip2.go
// Package bzip provides a writer that uses bzip2 compression (bzip.org).
package main
import "C"

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "testing"
    "unsafe"
)

type writer struct {
    w      io.Writer // underlying output stream
    stream *C.bz_stream
    outbuf [64 * 1024]byte
}

// Close flushes the compressed data and closes the stream.
// It does not close the underlying io.Writer.
func (w *writer) Close() error {
    if w.stream == nil {
        panic("closed")
    }
    defer func() {
        C.BZ2_bzCompressEnd(w.stream)
        C.bz2free(w.stream)
        w.stream = nil
    }()
    for {
        inlen, outlen := C.uint(0), C.uint(cap(w.outbuf))
        r := C.bz2compress(w.stream, C.BZ_FINISH, nil, &inlen,
            (*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(&w.outbuf)), &outlen)
        if _, err := w.w.Write(w.outbuf[:outlen]); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if r == C.BZ_STREAM_END {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

// NewWriter returns a writer for bzip2-compressed streams.
func NewWriter(out io.Writer) io.WriteCloser {
    const blockSize = 9
    const verbosity = 0
    const workFactor = 30
    w := &writer{w: out, stream: C.bz2alloc()}
    C.BZ2_bzCompressInit(w.stream, blockSize, verbosity, workFactor)
    return w
}

func main() {
    w := NewWriter(os.Stdout)
    if _, err := io.Copy(w, os.Stdin); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("bzipper: %v\n", err)
    }
    if err := w.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("bzipper: close: %v\n", err)
    }
}
```

First I compile the .c file:

```
gcc -I/usr/include -L/usr/lib -lbz2 --shared bzip2.c -fPIC -o libbzip2.so
```

The linux environment LD_LIBRARY_PATH contains ".", and then go build fails:

```
go build usebzip2.go
# command-line-arguments
/tmp/go-build677611698/b001/_x002.o: In function `_cgo_22d5d7fabfe4_Cfunc_bz2compress':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:118: undefined reference to `bz2compress'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So how to fix it? I'm using ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't run:

```
go build usebzip2.go
```

but rather:

```
go build
```

(and you don't need to invoke `gcc` directly on `bzip2.c`).  When you use this process, you'll get many more (but different) errors because you have not put in the right directives before the:

```
import "C"
```

line.  You need a comment (or series of comments) telling cgo about the functions you intend to provide, or providing those functions inline, and to direct the link phase to use `-lbz2`.  In particular, you will need to:

- `#include <bzlib.h>`
- provide a `bz2alloc` function
- provide a `bz2free` function
- provide a declaration for your `bz2compress` function
- set the `LDFLAGS` to include `-lbz2`

The actual `bz2alloc` and `bz2free` are short and simple and therefore can be included directly in this header block:

```
package main

/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -lbz2     
#include <bzlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
bz_stream *bz2alloc() { return calloc(1, sizeof(bz_stream)); }
int bz2compress(bz_stream *s, int action,
    char *in, unsigned *intlen, char *out, unsigned *outlen);
void bz2free(bz_stream* s) { free(s); }
*/      
import "C"
```

If you insert this and run `go build` you will now see a different and more useful error:

```
./usebzip2.go:60:2: cannot use w (type *writer) as type io.WriteCloser in return argument:
        *writer does not implement io.WriteCloser (missing Write method)
```

which is of course because `type writer` does not implement `Write`.

(There's a completed version of exercise 13.3—not mine—at https://github.com/torbiak/gopl/tree/master/ex13.3.  Note that they have augmented theirs to use locking as well, making it safe to call the write function from multiple goroutines simultaneously.)